# Cannot install managed or unmanaged package in Trailhead playground / developer account

Tags: appexchange, trailhead, superbadges, installedpackage

I am trying to install packages to complete my superbadges.

I tried creating a new playground ,tried creating a new developer account and linking it to my trailhead account. I tried with existing playground as well.

I am unable to install any package(I tried different packages for different superbadges) in any of the salesforce environments linked to my trailhead account.

I have followed all the steps listed in the trailhead to make sure the managed package URL reflects my salesforce URL.

I keep getting this error: Package not found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best resource for Trailhead issues is the [Help and Support page](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help). Click Connect with the Community to post to the community, or click Share your Feedback and then Trailhead Content Feedback to open a case with Salesforce